# Access log written in a file in restlet server

Tags: logging, restlet, access-log

In restlet server, Application logs written correctly in file, for access logs file created, but logs not stored in that file.

```
My logging.properties file:

handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler,org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler
.level=WARNING
org.restlet.level=ALL 

java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=100
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/logs/serverout-%u-%g.log

org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler.formatter=org.restlet.engine.log.DefaultAccessLogFormatter
org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler.limit=10000000
org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler.count=100
org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler.pattern=/logs/access-%u-%g.log


Any suggestions?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do 2 things,

1. configure some-logger-name in the logging.properties file.

   some-logger-name.handlers=org.restlet.engine.log.AccessLogFileHandler

   some-logger-name.useParentHandlers=false
2. Set the some-logger-name in your component java initialization code.

   component.getLogService().setLoggerName("some-logger-name");